# TYPO3 admin backend modules are missing

Tags: typo3, backend

I worked all day to get Xampp running and install TYPO3 on it. Now I'm logged in the backend, but many admin modules are not displayed, such as Templates, Access etc. - There must be something I've done wrong, but I've got no idea.
 [these are the modules shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa8Gq.jpg)
 Missing: View, Info, Functions, Template, Access, Backend Users, Log, DB Check, Configuration, Reports.

Comment: You already have an answer, but in the future it might be helpful to give more context such as how you installed TYPO3 (with composer etc.). I don't know why your question was downvoted, but this may be one of the reasons, in addition to the typos.

Comment: Since TYPO3 9 the Functions Module must be fetched from [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/func).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most backend modules are shipped as extensions, which can be installed, uninstalled, activated and deactivated.

If you installed TYPO3 by using the [traditional](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/QuickInstall/GetAndUnpack/Index.html) installation method (extracting the TYPO3 source package), go to **ADMIN TOOLS → Extensions** and make sure, the missing modules are activated. For example, "Log" is provided by the system extension `belog` and "Templates" by `tstemplate`. You can activate/deactivate extensions by clicking on the icon left-hand-side of their title.

If you installed TYPO3 by using [PHP Composer](http://getcomposer.org) (see [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/QuickInstall/Composer/Index.html)), make sure all packages are included in your `composer.json` file. For example `typo3/cms-belog`, `typo3/cms-tstemplate`, etc. You can add/remove packages with the following composer commands on the command line (for example `typo3/cms-belog`):

```
composer require typo3/cms-belog
composer remove typo3/cms-belog
```

In the unlikely event that this does not solve your issue, review file `typo3conf/PackageStates.php`. This file contains a list of all extensions (system extensions, as well as community extensions), currently available in your TYPO3 system.

Comment: Thanks a lot! - Its a little diffiuld to find the right Extensions, and it allway says, that my PHP-Version is to high - but it works!

Answer (score 10):

It could also be that your **admin** user, who may have been migrated from an older version, is not a newly introduced **system maintainer**.

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.0/Feature-82266-BackendUsersSystemMaintainers.html

If that is the case, you can easily create an new "system maintainer user" from the install environment. **Maintenance > Create Administrative User**

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The required extension were also present in PackageStates.php but still the backend menu options like Admins Tools, Extensions, Maintenance were not visible.

The reason was that that admin user was not listed as a System Maintainer

To make a backend user a System Maintainer do the following

1. Login with admin password to /typo3/install.php
2. Setting > Manage System Maintainers
3. select and save backend users you want as System Maintainers

Now go to backend at /typo3/ and you should see the "Admins Tools" menu options

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://get.typo3.org/misc/composer/helper to figure out the missing extensions. If you simply want to install all extensions, klick on TYPO3/FULL and copy and paste the code to your console.

`composer require "typo3/cms-about:^9.5" "typo3/cms-adminpanel:^9.5" "typo3/cms-backend:^9.5" "typo3/cms-belog:^9.5" "typo3/cms-beuser:^9.5" "typo3/cms-core:^9.5" "typo3/cms-extbase:^9.5" "typo3/cms-extensionmanager:^9.5" "typo3/cms-feedit:^9.5" "typo3/cms-felogin:^9.5" "typo3/cms-filelist:^9.5" "typo3/cms-filemetadata:^9.5" "typo3/cms-fluid:^9.5" "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content:^9.5" "typo3/cms-form:^9.5" "typo3/cms-frontend:^9.5" "typo3/cms-impexp:^9.5" "typo3/cms-indexed-search:^9.5" "typo3/cms-info:^9.5" "typo3/cms-install:^9.5" "typo3/cms-linkvalidator:^9.5" "typo3/cms-lowlevel:^9.5" "typo3/cms-opendocs:^9.5" "typo3/cms-recordlist:^9.5" "typo3/cms-recycler:^9.5" "typo3/cms-redirects:^9.5" "typo3/cms-reports:^9.5" "typo3/cms-rsaauth:^9.5" "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor:^9.5" "typo3/cms-scheduler:^9.5" "typo3/cms-seo:^9.5" "typo3/cms-setup:^9.5" "typo3/cms-sys-action:^9.5" "typo3/cms-sys-note:^9.5" "typo3/cms-t3editor:^9.5" "typo3/cms-taskcenter:^9.5" "typo3/cms-tstemplate:^9.5" "typo3/cms-viewpage:^9.5" "typo3/cms-workspaces:^9.5"`